# Why does the child div set to height: 100% not inheriting the Height from parent div set to min-height: 80px?

Tags: html, css

Fellow techies, I'm just wondering why after setting the Height property to 100% to the child div, it doesn't inherit the height value from the parent (whose min-height is set to 80px). But it works if I replace the min-height with height (80px).

Any Knowledge regarding this behavior is welcome. Please mind explaining without creating ambiguity as I am still a CSS toddler. Cheers!

```
HTML:

<header class="header">
<div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="logo">
        <span class="logo-icon">DM</span>
        Dominique Moore
    </a>

    <nav class="navbar">
        <ul class="navlist">
            <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">skills</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">about me</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
</header>

CSS:

 .header {
  min-height: 80px;

  }

.header .container {
 width: 100%;
 max-width: 75rem;
 height: 100%; 
 margin: 10px auto 0;
 padding-inline: 1.5rem;
 border-radius: 5rem;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
 background-color: var(--background-light);
 border: 1px solid red;
 }
```